# REST endpoint with @QuerydslPredicate Predicate mocking test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, predicate, querydsl

I have a rest controller which has parameter com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate that is annotated with @QuerydslPredicate

```
ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> listEmployees(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Employee.class) Predicate predicate) {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeService.listEmployees(predicate);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(employees , HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I have my unit test using spring runner. My unit test looks like

```
@Test
public void test_listEmployees() throws Exception {
    List<Employee> employees = singletonList(employee);

   given(employeeService.listEmployees(any(Predicate.class))).willReturn(employees);

    mockMvc.perform(get(EMPLOYEE_PATH)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].employeeId", is(employee.getEmployeeId())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].employeeName", is(employee.getEmployeeName())));
}
```

On unit test execution, I get following exception.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate]: Specified class is an interface

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:160)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate]: Specified class is an interface
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:101)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
... 47 more
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**

My controller class is annotated with

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "employees")
```

And my controller method is annotated with

```
@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET
)
```

Comment: I think you have to autowire predicate or create a real one and give it into the method.

Comment: Can't autowire predicate, rather have to create its instance. It didn't work.

Comment: why cant you autowire predicate? You can not create an instance of predicate itself. Its an interface.

Comment: @Maz, how is your controller annotated?

Comment: @Patrick, it says bean definition not found when I autowire.

Comment: @MarcTarin, I have edited my question with controller details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a break for few days and trying to understand the issue, I found out that it is not an issue with mockito `given` function. Rather, it is an issue with `mockmvc.perform` operation. I got it resolved by adding `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` annotation from spring-data-commons package in my test class.

Hurrrayyyyy